# How can I shorten this common pattern?

Tags: typescript, null, lodash, nullable

In our codebase we often encounter this pattern:

```
(_.isNil(x)) ? something(x) : null;
```

If something was a method on the object then the short version of it would be:

```
x?.something()
```

Is there a commonly accepted shortcut to the above? Perhaps something provided by lodash itself or some other library?
Thanks

Comment: `something()` should handle a "nullish" value

Comment: @Andreas I disagree. Sometimes `something()` doesn't make sense with nullable values. Also you'd have to put type guards on all functions otherwise a function that returned a non-nullable value would now return a nullable value and that propagates the nullable problem.

Comment: Does `x && something(x)` work for you? Adding type guards to the function is better, since either way you are adding clutter to the code, just if it's in the function there's less room for user error.